# Vertex $E$ of equilateral $\Delta ABE$ is in interior of $\square ABCD.$ $F$ is the midpoint of intersection of $AE$ and diagonal $BD$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, problem-solving

> Vertex $E$ of equilateral $\Delta ABE$ is in interior of $\square ABCD.$ $F$ is the midpoint of intersection of $AE$ and diagonal $BD$. If $AB = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3}}$ and $[\Delta ABF] = A$, find $(4A)^2$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

From a bit of angle chasing, we have the angles of $\Delta ABF$ . 
Also $AB = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3}}$, let $AF = y$. We have :-
$$\frac{y}{\sin B} = \frac{AB}{\sin C}$$
We have $\sin 75^\circ = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$ , so :-

$$\rightarrow y = \frac{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3}} * \sqrt{2}}{\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}*2}$$

Let $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3}} = k$. After continuous solving we will have :-
$$y = \frac{2\sqrt{k}}{k}$$
From here I can get $$[\Delta ABF] = \frac{1}{2}(AB)(AF)\sin 60^\circ$$
$$\rightarrow \sqrt{k} * \frac{2\sqrt{k}}{k} * \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\rightarrow [\Delta ABF] = \sqrt{3}$$

Hence $(4A)^2 = 48$ .

The question is, am I correct? Was it a coincidence that the $k$'s got cancelled out? 
I am probably not correct, because right now I found out that $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3}} < \sqrt{3}$ , and this is impossible if my answer would have correct.

Can anyone let me know where I went wrong? Thank You.

Comment: $AB$ is not $\sqrt k$, it is $k$

Comment: Oh, did I proceed making that tiny silly mistake?

Comment: I see that in the formula for $[\triangle ABF]$

Comment: But, if that is the case I am getting the answer as $\sqrt{3(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3)}}}$ , is this the correct answer?

Comment: The formula for $y$ in terms of $k$ is also wrong

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: I have no idea. It seems like a perfectly valid question, and you showed your work as well. So it does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use $AB=k=\sqrt{1+\sqrt 3}$. Then $$\sin 75^\circ=\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}=\frac {k^2}{2\sqrt 2}$$
Area of triangle $ABF$ is then:
$$[\triangle ABF]=\frac12 AB\cdot AF\sin60^\circ=\frac12 k\frac {k\sin 45^\circ}{\sin 75^\circ}\sin 60^\circ\\=\frac 12 k^2\frac{\frac{\sqrt 2}2}{\frac{k^2}{2\sqrt 2}}\frac{\sqrt 3}2=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$$